# carriage return / line feed removal with do-while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Yo guys,

I used google and this website, but could not find an in depth explanation of a little part in the following code:

```
// Guess the letter game, 4th version.
class Guess4 {
 public static void main(String args[])
 throws java.io.IOException {
  char ch, answer = 'K';

do {
 System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between A and Z.");
 System.out.print("Can you guess it: ");
 // read a letter, but skip cr/lf
 do {
  ch = (char) System.in.read(); // get a char
 } while(ch == '\n' | ch == '\r');

if(ch == answer) System.out.println("** Right **");
else {
 System.out.print("...Sorry, you're ");
 if(ch < answer) System.out.println("too low");
 else System.out.println("too high");
 System.out.println("Try again!\n");
   }
  } while(answer != ch);
 }
}
```

So my question is about this part:

```
do {ch = (char) System.in.read(); 
} while(ch == '\n' | ch == '\r');
```

Can somebody explain in depth how this works? I know that it's reading a character from the keyboard first, because a do-while loop runs at least one time. The | means that both of them have to be false in order to let the do-while loop stops. In which order this works? So when i am pressing a letter, it first gets a carriage return and line feed, both true, so it runs the system.in.read again, but then it runs twice and it also has my letter already, so when system.in.read runs again because of the loop, it produces again a carriage return and line feed, or not? So in my mind it becomes an infinite loop, but it is not. I tried running the program without this and when i press a letter it prints the two questions, two times. Why? I am a little confused about how this loop and removal of this cr/nl works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Read tutorial on java operators and ask questions if you still don't get them, not the other way around. In case you wonder why your question got downvoted.

Comment: I understand the operator, but it's the order i don't get. First i type H for example, then i press enter, and a newline also is produced. So while condition is still true and it runs again the System.in.read but i already typed a H, so it should go to the else part. Or maybe it just reads the second time if there is a new character left? And i searched in tutorials and on google for at least 30 minutes before coming here. Again, i understand how the | operator works, it's just that i don't understand what happens if it returns again to System.in.read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ch = (char)System.in.read();` reads a new `char` into `ch` in each iteration of the loop. The loop continues as long as the input character is either a new line (`\n`) or a line feed (`\r`). Any other input ends the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the any other input then \n or \r ends the loop. But i type H for example, then it produces automatically an enter after i press enter and a newline. Then it runs true in the while loop and it goes back to system.in.read, but System.in.read will then wait for a new character? Or does it store H and loops until the \n and \r is gone or something? I don;t really get the order of this. Because it will print the question two times after i remove this loop from the program, i tested this.

Comment: @Simon System.in returns an InputStream. The Javadoc of InputStream.read says that `This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown`. Therefore, yes, if there's no input available, it waits for a new character.

Comment: So, it runs one time, after which i choose to type a H. I give an enter after this, so the while receives the enter and newline. Then the loop iterates and it waits for another character. But when i run the program, it does not immediately asks for a new character, but it goes to the else part and prints Sorry you're wrong and that i am too low and try again. This i don't get, i am sorry, but i still don't get it how the do-while loop prevents that the program goes immediately to the sorry you're wrong part.